# How can i trim a blank(empty) line in NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have textView where user can add text in new line. but when user enter multiple new line and not enter a any text then i want skip all that line and just use only one new line.

I have String like below.

```
Hello,



How r u?
```

I want a string like this

```
Hello
How r u?
```

I have tried this but not working

```
strContects=[strContects stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

How can i do this?

Hope u will understand?

Comment: "Not working" is useless for helping us help you. What result does that code give you? Be specific. You also need to tell us what kind of possibilities your input string will have. Does it always have a particular number of excess blank lines, or can there be a different number of lines?

Comment: @rdelmar i have updated my question. hope u will understand now

Comment: Try replacing \r instead of \n? Also, to be clear you're using NSMutableString, right? What type is "strContects"?

Comment: @mc01 means I have to replace \n\n with  \r..?

Comment: There are different types of return characters. Different combinations of \n and \r. Use the debugger to figure out _exactly_ what characters your string contains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace multiple occurrence of omit multiple newline characters with single one by following regular expressions code

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\n+" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length]) withTemplate:@"\n"];
```

this will print

Hello,

How r u?  //in new line(all \n omitted with single \n)

Answer (score 1):

If the goal here is removing *all* blank lines - not just consolidating multiple newlines - then it is worth noting the accepted answer wont remove an initial blank line in the string; eg "\nHello..."

A bit more involved, but try this category:

```
- (NSString*)stringByRemovingBlankLines
{
    NSScanner *scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self];
    NSMutableString *string = NSMutableString.new;
    while (!scan.isAtEnd) {
        [scan scanCharactersFromSet:NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet intoString:NULL];
        NSString *line = nil;
        [scan scanUpToCharactersFromSet:NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet intoString:&line];
        if (line) [string appendFormat:@"%@\n",line];
    }
    if (string.length) [string deleteCharactersInRange:(NSRange){string.length-1,1}]; // drop last '\n'
    return string;
}
```

(BTW - this can also handle other types of 'newline' characters which the accepted answer does not. This wasn't asked for, but it came up in the comments)